# Programmatically searching google without API-Key in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to program a request to Google without an API-Key?
I've tried out several Python packages and their works fine, except they deliver links even then when Google says not results found. It would also be nice, if the short page description below the links will be delivered aswell.

Answer (score 1):

For scraping Google Search Results you can using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library.

The request might be blocked if you use `requests`, since the default user-agent library in `requests` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) because Google might consider you a bot.

To bypass possible blocking, you can add `headers` with your real [User-Agent](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/) to the code.

The next step could be [rotate `user-agent`](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents), for example, to switch between PC, mobile, and tablet, as well as between browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and so on. The most reliable way is to use rotating proxies, user-agents, and a captcha solver.

If we need to dynamically extract all results from all possible pages, we need to use a while loop with a specific condition to exit the loop [which is non-token based pagination](https://python.plainenglish.io/pagination-techniques-to-scrape-data-from-any-website-in-python-779cd32bd514#74dc). It will go through all of them, no matter how many pages there are. Basically, we don't hard-code the page numbers to go from N to N pages.

Check code in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scraping-google-search-pagination-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": "web scraping", # query example
    "hl": "en",          # language
    "gl": "uk",          # country of the search, UK -> United Kingdom
    "start": 0,          # number page by default up to 0
    #"num": 100          # parameter defines the maximum number of results to return.
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

page_limit = 10           # page limit, if you do not need to parse all pages
page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    page_num += 1
    print(f"page: {page_num}")
        
    html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    
    for result in soup.select(".tF2Cxc"):
        title = result.select_one(".DKV0Md").text
        try:
           snippet = result.select_one(".lEBKkf span").text
        except:
           snippet = None
        links = result.select_one(".yuRUbf a")["href"]
      
        data.append({
          "title": title,
          "snippet": snippet,
          "links": links
        })

    if page_num == page_limit:
        break
    if soup.select_one(".d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]"):
        params["start"] += 10
    else:
        break
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Web scraping - Wikipedia",
    "snippet": "Scraping a web page involves fetching it and extracting from it. Fetching is the downloading of a page (which a browser does when a user views a page).",
    "links": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping"
  },
  {
    "title": "What Is Scraping | About Price & Web Scraping Tools - Imperva",
    "snippet": "Web scraping is the process of using bots to extract content and data from a website. Unlike screen scraping, which only copies pixels displayed onscreen, web ...",
    "links": "https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/web-scraping-attack/"
  },
  other results...
]
```

---

Also, you can use third-party API like [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan. It will require an API key though. It's an API that returns the same results as you would see while browsing.

The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import json, os

params = {
  "api_key": "...",                  # serpapi key from https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
  "engine": "google",                # serpapi parser engine
  "q": "web scraping",               # search query
  "gl": "uk",                        # country of the search, UK -> United Kingdom
  "num": "100"                       # number of results per page (100 per page in this case)
  # other search parameters: https://serpapi.com/search-api#api-parameters
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)      # where data extraction happens

page_limit = 10
organic_results_data = []
page_num = 0

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()    # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
    page_num += 1
    
    for result in results["organic_results"]:
        organic_results_data.append({
            "title": result.get("title"),
            "snippet": result.get("snippet"),
            "link": result.get("link")
        })

    if page_num == page_limit:
        break
      
    if "next_link" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", []):
        search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get("serpapi_pagination").get("next_link")).query)))
    else:
        break
    
print(json.dumps(organic_results_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output: exactly the same as in the previous solution.

Answer (score 0):

Importing lxml is not needed as it is used by beautifulsoup internally, though I did need to `pip install lxml --upgrade`. Weird.

So anyway, here's my slightly modified version of Denis' non-serpapi code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import random
import requests


countrycode = "DE"
params = {
    "q": f"web scraping {countrycode}",       # NOTE query NOTE
    "start": 0,
    "num": 4,       # NOTE parameter defines the maximum number of results to return NOTE
}

uas_list = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/77.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/77.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36",
]
header = {"User-Agent": random.choice(uas_list)}

data = []

while True:
    print(f"header: {header['User-Agent']}")

    html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, 
headers=header, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

    for result in soup.select(".tF2Cxc"):
        title_elem = result.select_one(".DKV0Md")
        link_elem = result.select_one(".yuRUbf a")
        snippet_elem = result.select_one(".VwiC3b span")

    # check if the elements before accessing attributes
        if title_elem:
            title = title_elem.text
        else:
            title = "Title not found"
        if snippet_elem:
            snippet = snippet_elem.text
        else:
            snippet = "Snippet not found"
        if link_elem and "href" in link_elem.attrs:
            link = link_elem["href"]
        else:
            link = "Link not found"

        data.append({
            "title": title,
            "link": link,
            "snippet": snippet,
        })

    if soup.select_one(".d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]"):
        params["start"] += 10
    else:
        break

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

I mostly want to point out I was getting 'null' for "snippet" so after bunch of digging and examining the code in the dev console, I found a new class they're using to contain the description-information (snippet_elem = result.select_one(".VwiC3b span")).

Sorry, if my answer is not formatted properly, I'm not used to this way of formatting code without visual cues.
Cheers!